# DNN 9 HTML Module wont disable "Allow Indexing" option

Tags: dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am trying to prevent a DNN module from showing on internal search results.

I have unticked the Allow Indexing option, but every time when I open the module it did not save the setting.

I am currently using DNN 9.04.01

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also delete the index and restart the application pool after applying this setting.